# column conditions in where clause shows error

Tags: cakephp

```
public function search() {
         $this->loadmodel('Usermgmt.User');
        if ($this->request -> isPost()) {
            $this->User->set($this->data);
            $keyword=$this->data['Doctors']['search'];

    $this->paginate['limit'] = 3; 
 $result = $this->paginate('User',array('conditions'=>$cond));
  $this->set('result', $result);


        }
```

here where cause shows Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'conditions' in 'where clause' it is cakephp-2.4.5

Comment: try $result = $this->paginate('User',array($cond));

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for paginate is [$conditions](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#1070-1081) therefore:

```
$result = $this->paginate('User', $cond);
```

Here's a further example:

```
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate(
    'Recipe',
    array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%')
);
```

There's [more information about pagination in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html).